# Tokens and Resubmissions

Tags: php

I've looked at several questions on here and can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I have a program that creates a hidden token field to check if the user actually sent it from that page which was nice but now I found out that each page that it creates a token it makes the last page only valid. I'm not opting for a one token created per session, and I have a header 303 without replace eg:

```
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], false, 303);
```

When this code runs I see the header works with refresh I don't get the 'resubmit data?' and I have data being echoed after the header and it appears that it doesn't echo it.

I like the per page works nicely with postback data but only for the last page requested and for the per session w/303 the repost/token works but it won't echo the data after the header. Or is there some other way to allow tokens and disable resubmit data and be able to echo the data I need the user to see?

If you need some sample code I'll be glad to edit this post.

Comment: One token per session is enough.

Comment: @zerkms I beg to differ! Imagine the user taking a very liberal dose of "open link in new tab", then submitting in random order. This in fact makes the user-visible state at submit time non-deterministic.

Comment: @Eugen Rieck: I don't see your point. > 1 tokens per session bring nothing to security, but a lot of headache.

Comment: I like to use just one token per session. Its just that after adding a header to not allow reposting data that it doesn't allow a echo saying 'successfully entered data' or such.

Comment: @zerkms I am not talking about security at all (even though I disagree with the notion, that single-use tokens do not add a layer of security: They make session stealing end the legitimate user's session, which he is likely to notice), I am talking about business logic: A token per request makes assures us not only from which page the user submittetd, but also from which instance of the page.

Comment: @Eugen Rieck: "They make session stealing end the legitimate user's session, which he is likely to notice" --- these tokens have nothing to do with session hijacking - they are against CSRF.

Comment: @Eugen Rieck: "A token per request makes assures us not only from which page the user submittetd, but also from which instance of the page" --- if only it was required. The solution in your answer doesn't allow that anyway.

Comment: @zerkms Again: My motivation is business logic. The fact, that single use tokens help protect against session theft is a welcome side effect (in this use case)

Comment: @Eugen Rieck: I don't see where you found it's something about business logic in the question. And there is a pattern to solve the issue without any tokens: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: @zerkms Could you elaborate, how my answer disallows this?

Comment: @Eugen Rieck: you only store token + expiry date, not the page it should be sent from.

Comment: @zerkms Ah! that is the misunderstanding: I assume the mapping of token to page to be already solved, as the OQ states "... that creates a hidden token field to check if the user actually sent it from that page ...", which indicates to me, that checking a token against a page is already done.

Comment: I'm still a little confused which option is better for my program. I like the per session but I can't echo my message after I use header. And if I use the per request how should I limit amount of tokens eg: if a user happens to open many windows which creates one for each. And for the per request what would be the time out range 5-10 min? Also I'd have to have a function that loops through the token session and deletes all expired tokens then check if token is in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, you store the token in the session - so the simplest way to resolve this would be not to store a **single** token, but a **list** of tokens, each with an expiry date.

So whenever you create a page with a token, you append it to the list. Whenever you verify a token, you cycle the list, expunge the expired tokens, verify against all valid ones.

Comment: Any technical reason to create more than one token?

Comment: In a way I can see this as a good idea, but a user could open many pages that create individual tokens and I'm not sure how much data you can enter into a session variable.

Comment: @Class: Assuming a token is somewhere near 256 bits, this makes it 32 bytes. You can store quite a lot of those in a session

Comment: @zerkms I outlined my reasons in the question's comments

Comment: I'm going with this one for the time being since it's the best way to deal with what I need to accomplish. I also added a foreach loop to delete all expired session tokens. I would have liked to use just one token, but in doing so it wouldn't display my output after my header 303 to eliminate reposting/resubmitting data.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why data *would* be seen in the browser. (It might actually be printing, just not used. Debug via telnet, packet capture, or some other means of capturing header content, if that's important.)

... I think your issue comes from expecting the POST content to be resent or otherwise viewed. It won't be: 303 redirects are (by specification) followed via a GET. Once the browser sees the 303 redirect and Location header, it will follow the new URL and ignore content of the response.

Comment: So you're saying after the header it ignores the rest of the script or its expecting to only use/echo GET's. Because in my program I have if things are OK create header and later on in the html echo the message I have for the user and I have no need for GET/POST's.

Comment: You need to be more specific with your pronouns. After the 303 header, the *browser* ignores payload content, and follows the redirect. (While PHP will continue to process the page after the `header` call.) The browser follows the redirect by using with a GET no matter the original HTTP method, and any previously sent payload is lost.